# Android .. ListView Crash when i scroll Down with sorta along dapter feeding it ..

Tags: android, listview, crash

When i scroll down my list view it work normally with few element but when it has more element it crash once i scroll down .. i need some one to explain me where is the prob and how to fix it .. thx in advance

This is the adapter where OurContact.contacts_names is arraylist:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, OurContact.contacts_names);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using CustomAdapter for recycling memory to prevent crashing...it is better way of using ListView efficiently

create a layout for Listitem in res/layout folder

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#333333" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And create your CustomAdapter

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> categories=null;
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> categories) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item,categories);
        this.categories=categories;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView cat;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.cat=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
         holder.cat.setText(categories.get(position));
         return convertView; 
    }

}
```

Now just Use this Adapter to populate ListView

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter<String>(this,OurContact.contacts_names));
```

Comment: it Still Crash even with me using Custom Adapter